# iOS AVPlayer EXC_BAD_ACCESS when accessing properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, avplayer

I'm working on a plugin for Apache Cordova that will allow audio streaming from a remote URL through the Media API.

The issue that I'm experiencing is that I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` signal whenever I try to access certain properties on the `AVPlayer` instance. `currentTime` and `isPlaying` are the worst offenders. The player will be playing sound through the speakers, but as soon as my code reaches a `player.currentTime` or `[player currentTime]` it throws the bad access signal.

```
[player play];
double position = round([player duration] * 1000) / 1000;
[player currentTime]; //This will cause the signal
```

I am using ARC, so I'm not releasing anything that shouldn't be.

**Edit:**

Everything that I've done has been hacking around on the Cordova 3 CDVSound class as a proof of concept for actual streaming on iOS.

The original code can be found here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media/tree/master/src/ios

My code can be found here:

*[CDVSound.h](https://gist.github.com/grep-awesome/3303958456e1db855394)*

*[CDVSound.m](https://gist.github.com/grep-awesome/42f060125a298d73e124)*

The method `startPlayingAudio` will trip an `exc_bad_access` at line 346. Removing line 346 will cause audio to play, but it will trip a bad access later down the road when `getCurrentPositionAudio` and line 532 is called.

**Edit / Solution**

So it turns out that the best way to handle this is to use a AVPlayerItem and then access it with `player.currentItem.currentTime`. The real question then becomes, why isn't this behavior documented with `AVPlayer` and why does it behave like this?

Comment: What is audioFile? If it is a custom class of yours can you show how you go about creating the player in it?

Comment: audioFile is a custom class, but it is irrelevent to this example. The `player` property does exist and is playing sound.

Comment: With what is provided here I cannot see an issue, it would help to see more code around how the class that holds the player.

Comment: @SkillM2 I've added all of my code, links to original code, and additional explanation into my question. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: Sorry, I was away, I'm happy to see you've solved it. In the AVPlayer class reference they do mention that the currentTime returns the current time of the current item but they could be more explicit about the usage of AVPlayerItem. I guess you've changed to use initWithPlayerItem:  now.

Comment: @SkillM2 yeah, I'm using `initWithPlayerItem` now. It is definitely very poorly documented. I noticed with I was using `initWithUrl` that it would throw a bad access when trying to access the `currentItem` property. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: How has this worked for you so far were you able to test with other files like a m3u8 audio? I've been looking for a similar solution.

Comment: @greaterKing This has worked with AAC and MP3 files and is in production now, but I haven't tried any other file types.